# Android | Navigation | OnDestroyView() is not getting called

Tags: android, navigation, android-lifecycle, fragment-oncreateview

I have a activity that hold bottomNavigation which is using compose-navigation (navController) to navigate to and from each tab. It works fine when I am navigating between tabs everything gets called and works.

The problem is when i launch another activity which is a ideally a host for another fragment, by bottomNav's fragment's onDestoryView() is not getting called.

Flow: Launch BottomNav Activity -> Hosts Home Fragment -> Home Fragment opens new activity which holds Edit Home Fragment (in which there is no bottomNav).

I've very less knowledge about this case, so far i've tested that by Home Fragmnet's onResume() is getting called, and my actual want is to launch onCreateView() of home fragment when user comes back from edit home fragment to home fragment and update the UI with whatever user changed in edit home.

Comment: Your fragment's views don't get destroyed when you move to a new activity (unless you have the developer option of 'Don't keep activities' on), that's to be expected. Why does the view being destroyed and recreated make a difference? You shouldn't be using that for any of your logic.

Comment: No my logic is simple which gives a refreshed view to user so lets say, i have both fragment in same activity now when i navigate forward i get onDestoryView() on home fragment and when i come back it calls onCreateView() which automatically gets the new updated data to show to user

Comment: That's not what you should be relying on to get fresh data and that is actually the root cause of your issue. Maybe you should post a different question with your specific fragment's code and where you get your data from so you can get help changing that to get it from a `Flow` or `LiveData` that automatically refreshes when your underlying data changes.